# python 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'

Tags: python, speed-test

I am trying to get the download and upload speed in python by using the "speedtest" module, but it gives me that error when I use the module:

AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'.

and I was only declaring the variable,
that is my code :

```
import speedtest

speedtester = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

The module actually doesn't have the functions for some reason.
Please tell me what is wrong with my code I was sure to import the module from the cmd and also the pycharm terminal and still got the same error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you could have a file called `speedtest.py` in the same directory as your script, which would override the actual module. If that's the case, rename it to something else. Otherwise, if that's not the case, maybe tell us how you installed the module, what version got installed, and what Python version you have.

Comment: @RandomDavis I moved the speedtest.py to the same folder as the script and it worked thanks for helping.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I said to do; you got the module and moved it _into_ the same directory as your script? I don't know why you did that, where you got the module's file, or what your issue even was.

Comment: @RandomDavis i got the file in PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages when it was installed and the issue was that the module itself wasn't working it didn't give me suggestions when I did "speedtest." and it gave me that error I talked about in the question when I tried to type "speedtest.Speedtest()" without the auto complete (suggestions) and the my script's name is different from the module's name so that is why i moved the module to the script directory because they were different names and i didn't have to rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved after moving the speedtest.py file to the same directory as my script and it worked just fine. So just make sure the file is in the same folder as your python script.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue. I was using PyCharm IDE.
The issue occurs when you install **speedtest** using `pip install speedtest`
In order to solve the above mentioned issue, you need to use the following command.

```
pip install speedtest-cli
```

But before doing this, uninstall the previous one by using `pip uninstall speedtest`
[Screenshot to installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bv00.png)

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error. Then I google the problem and eventually came here. Later I realised that I have named my python file `speedtest.py`. I renamed it to something else (which is not the name of any python module) and it works just fine now.

[<--Screenshot-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc1BW.png)

So make sure this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed "speedtest" and "speedtest-cli"  libraries together then this issue will arise.

So first uninstall "speedtest" library using "pip uninstall speedtest" command.

Then try your code like :

"import speedtest
st = speedtest.Speedtest()
print(st.download()/1024)"

You will get output

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall before speedtest whit the command 'pip uninstall speedtest' . After that, this use this code to find download and upload, speeds and ping:

```
import speedtest

test = speedtest.Speedtest()

print("Loading server list...")
test.get_servers()
print("Choosing best server...")
best = test.get_best_server()

print(f"Found: {best['host']} located in {best['country']}")

print("Performing download test...")
download_result = test.download()
print("Performing upload test...")
upload_result = test.upload()
ping_result = test.results.ping

print(f"Download speed: {download_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f}Mbit/s")
print(f"Upload speed: {upload_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f}Mbit/s")
print(f"Ping: {ping_result}ms")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

i was also facing the same issue , what i have done is :
**i have uninstall the speedtest and speedtest-cli**

> pip uninstall speedtest

> pip uninstall speedtest-cli

**then again  install speedtest-cli**

> pip install speedtest-cli

Comment: Solved also my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. in pytho3 we cannot use the following code directly

```
import speedtest
wifi = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

Then it will give the error **python 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'**

Instead of that we can use following lines, it will support for Python3

```
from speedtest import Speedtest

internet = Speedtest()

download_speed = internet.download()
upload_speed = internet.upload() 

print("Download \t:", download_speed)
print("Upload   \t:", upload_speed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall **speedtest** if installed

```bash
pip uninstall speedtest
```

Install **speedtest-cli**

```bash
pip install speedtest-cli
```

Your code should look like

```py
import speedtest

st = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

And make sure **not** to name **your python script** as *speedtest.py*

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing the same issue about 'speedtest has no attribute "Speedtest" '. Don't worry the follow the steps:-

1. Avoid to name your file name speedtest.py
2. Simply update your speedtest module using
   pip install --upgrade speedtest-cli
3. Then unistall the previous speedtest using
   pip uninstall speedtest
4. After this, check the speedtest attribute using
   import speedtest
   print(dir(speedtest))
5. Then all the attributes are showing, search *Speedtest()*, if it's coming there then well done. And don't change the order of my steps. First upgrade then uninstall. It's working 100% in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into the issue and investigated the content of the module...
It appears what inside my venv folder I got a module folder "speedtest" with EMPTY **init**.py file and that is it...
Next to the folder was speedtest.py with actual code...
So deleting the empty folder/module helped me...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem,but main problem might be you are installing speedtest library which is not suitable instead use **pip install speedtest-cli** but before that remember to delete the previous one using **pip uninstall speedtest** and check the spelling of **get_servers** which is in the plural form

Answer (score 0):

If the problem still persists you could simply delete the current code archive and create another one, probably it could be a trash problem, at least for me it finally worked. And for those is still getting the http error, just put `secure = True`

Example:

```
st = speedtest.Speedtest(secure = True);
```